# Intergraph TerramapServer and PostGIS

Tags: postgis, intergraph

Has anyone ever used the two of them together, and if so, any special caveat to be aware of ?

Furthermore, does it even make sense to use PostGIS / do TerramapServers have their own storage format instead ?

Comment: TerramapServer? Do you mean Terrashare?

Comment: Nope, I mean Intergraph's TerramapServer (http://www.terramapserver.com/en/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the question is probably irrelevant because from what I could gather, you can only access even custom servers via its webservices (a.k.a. no direct upload to the filesystem/database), so the method by which they store/organize data doesn't really matter because it acts like a black box.